# User specific redirect on login, in Joomla

Tags: redirect, joomla, authentication

I'm looking for a way to redirect each user that logs in to a different page.  I do photography and want my clients to be able to log in then be redirected to a page that displays their pictures only.  Additionally, that specific user will be the only one to be able to view that page.  I know you can redirect all users after logging in to a specific page and hide certain content from those not logged in but that is not what I'm looking for... it needs to be user specific.  I'm new to Joomla and looking for a way to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure if there is any existing extension to manage this, but the actual redirection will likely need to happen in a user plugin. There is a trigger for after logging in that would let you figure out which user it is and then set the redirect.

Comment: because there are lots of complexities with this type of plugin, but can try to redirect according to their user group.

Answer (score 0):

If you install FLEXIcontent CCK and use that for content creation - 
it enables you to set up individual pages per user:

- http://www.flexicontent.org/forum/index.php?f=20&t=6762&rb_v=viewtopic
- http://www.flexicontent.org/forum/index.php?f=20&t=6132&rb_v=viewtopic

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for how I solved this...

I did some research on this and came across a plugin called Phoca Gallery.  It doesn't redirect the user to a specific page but rather lets you set viewing rights to specific users.  So I created a "Client Page" that only shows to registered users (i.e. when someone is login in) and have the joomla login module redirect all users to that page after login.

Now on my "Client Page" I have the phoca gallery module set to only show albums that the user has rights to.  A good work around for what I needed.  It even lets you add watermarks to your images... a good bonus... and an even better bonus... It's free!

Find it here: http://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery